# Un Cuestionario

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer que las preguntas junto con sus respuestas (opciones) se cargen de manera aleatoria.

Ya puse las preguntas con sus opciones, lo único que necesito hacer es que cada vez que recarge la página las preguntas junto con sus opciones se cambien de lugar de manera aleatoria y también que las preguntas no se repitan.

Ya intente varias cosas pero no se cómo lo podría hacer, vi que para poder hacerlo se utilizaba `Math.random()` pero no tengo la menor idea de dónde ponerlo o qué hacer.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Evament JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css(cliente)/o.css">
    <h1>Examen de JavaScript</h1>
    <script>
        var questions=[
        {
            quetion:"pregunta1",
            choiceA:"res1a",
            choiceB:"res2a",
            choiceC:"res3a",
            correct:"B",
        },{
            quetion:"pregunta2",
            choiceA:"res1b",
            choiceB:"res2",
            choiceC:"res3b",
            correct:"C",
        },{
            quetion:"pregunta3",
            choiceA:"res1c",
            choiceB:"res2c",
            choiceC:"res3c",
            correct:"A",
        }
        ];
        function startq(){
            for (i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
                document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+='<form id="quetion">';
                document.forms[i].innerHTML+=(i+1)+'.-'+questions[i].quetion;
                document.forms[i].innerHTML+='<label>'+questions[i].choiceA+'<input type="radio" value="A" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
                document.forms[i].innerHTML+='<label>'+questions[i].choiceB+'<input type="radio" value="B" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
                document.forms[i].innerHTML+='<label>'+questions[i].choiceC+'<input type="radio" value="C" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
                document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+="</form><br><br>"
                }
            document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+='<button onclick="result()">Evaluar</button>';
            }
            function result(){
                var aciertos=0;
                var x;
                var puntaje=10/3;
                var calificacion=0;
                for(i=0;i< document.forms.length;i++){
                    x=document.forms[i];
                    console.log(x);
                for(j=0;j<x.length;j++){
                    if (x[j].checked) {
                        console.log(x[j].value);
                        if (x[j].value==questions[i].correct) {
                            aciertos+=1;
                            calificacion=calificacion+puntaje;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("Numero de aciertos:"+ aciertos);
            console.log("Tu calificacion es: "+calificacion);
        }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="startq()">Iniciar</button>
    <div id="questions">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte más básica, puedes valerte de `Math.random()` para generar números aleatorios. Esta función te devuelve un número entre 0.0 y 0.9999999999999->, por lo que, para seleccionar un elemento de una lista, la técnica utilizada multiplicar su resultado por la cantidad de elementos de la lista.

Dado que quieres que las preguntas no se repitan, la forma más práctica de hacerlo es ir eliminando los elementos *seleccionados* del arreglo original, de manera que en dicho arreglo solamente tenga los elementos que aún se pueden seleccionar.

Finalmente, ya que necesitas procesar el resultado, yo sugiero tener un arreglo a donde se trasladen las *preguntas* que ya se seleccionaron.

Esto nos obliga a hacer varios cambios a tu código, los he colocado todos en un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de manera que puedas probar la solución aquí mismo en el navegador.

Para hacerlo más *real*, he agrandado el arreglo de *preguntas*, de las cuales cada ejecución selecciona y muestra aleatoriamente 3 al usuario. He ajustado el programa de manera que la validación de las respuestas se hace de manera correcta.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Evament JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css(cliente)/o.css">
    <h1>Examen de JavaScript</h1>
    <script>
        var selectedquestions = [];
        var questions=[
          {quetion:"pregunta0",choiceA:"res1a",choiceB:"res2a",choiceC:"res3a",correct:"A",
        },{quetion:"pregunta1",choiceA:"res1a",choiceB:"res2a",choiceC:"res3a",correct:"B",
        },{quetion:"pregunta2",choiceA:"res1b",choiceB:"res2",choiceC:"res3b",correct:"C",
        },{quetion:"pregunta3",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"A",
        },{quetion:"pregunta4",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"B",
        },{quetion:"pregunta5",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"C",
        },{quetion:"pregunta6",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"A",
        },{quetion:"pregunta7",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"B",
        },{quetion:"pregunta8",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"C",
        },{quetion:"pregunta9",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"A",
        },{quetion:"pregunta10",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"B",
        },{quetion:"pregunta11",choiceA:"res1c",choiceB:"res2c",choiceC:"res3c",correct:"C",
        }
        ];
        function startq() {
          for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
            document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+='<form id="quetion' + j + '">';
            document.forms[j].innerHTML+=(j+1) + '.- ' + questions[i].quetion;
            document.forms[j].innerHTML+='&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>' + questions[i].choiceA + '<input type="radio" value="A" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
            document.forms[j].innerHTML+='<label>'+questions[i].choiceB+'<input type="radio" value="B" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
            document.forms[j].innerHTML+='<label>'+questions[i].choiceC+'<input type="radio" value="C" name="p'+i+'"><span></span></label>';
            document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+="</form><br><br>"
            selectedquestions.push(questions[i]);
            questions.splice(i, 1);
          }
          document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML+='<button onclick="result()">Evaluar</button>';
        }
        function result() {
          var aciertos=0;
          var x;
          var puntaje=10/3;
          var calificacion=0;
          for(i=0; i< document.forms.length; i++) {
            x = document.forms[i];
            console.log(x);
            for(j=0; j < x.length; j++) {
              if (x[j].checked) {
                console.log(x[j].value);
                if (x[j].value == selectedquestions[i].correct) {
                  aciertos += 1;
                  calificacion = calificacion + puntaje;
                }
             }
           }
         }
         console.log("Numero de aciertos:"+ aciertos);
         console.log("Tu calificacion es: "+calificacion);
       }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="startq()">Iniciar</button>
    <div id="questions">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar Math.floor(Math.random() * TamañoDeTuarreglo) para que las preguntas sean en orden aleatorio, yo recomendaria un do while para remover el elemento de este y no se repita la pregunta, para el caso de las respuestas seria muy similar

```
do{
  indice=Math.floor(Math.random() * TamañoDeTuarreglo);
  array[indice].quetion;
  
}while (array >= 1);
```

Comment: me podrias decir porfavor en que parte de mi codigo tendria que ir?

Comment: en lugar de tu for que se encuentra en tu función startq, si mi explicacion te funciono agradeceria que no olvidaras marcarla como aceptada

Comment: @miacarmen en caso de haberte ayudado agradeceria votaras mi respuestay la marcaras como aceptada